# the ia does not leave eyes the Player ue4 C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I’m coding an ia with a c++ behavior tree. My concern is the fact that must follow the player then if he sees it more that returns in the other sequences.
So I used a UPawnSensingComponent and in my mycharacter.cpp: I put as code:

```
{
    // Set this character to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    //Initializing the pawn sensing component
    PawnSensingComp = CreateDefaultSubobject<UPawnSensingComponent>(TEXT("PawnSensingComp"));
    //Set the peripheral vision angle to 90 degrees
    PawnSensingComp->SetPeripheralVisionAngle(90.f);
    

    
    //Create socket to getItem
    FP_FistLocation = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("FistLocation"));
    FP_FistLocation->SetupAttachment(GetCapsuleComponent());
    
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AAICharacter::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    //Register the function that is going to fire when the character sees a Pawn
    if (PawnSensingComp)
    {
        PawnSensingComp->OnSeePawn.AddDynamic(this, &AAICharacter::OnSeePlayer);
    }
    
}

// Called every frame
void AAICharacter::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void AAICharacter::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

}

void AAICharacter::OnSeePlayer(APawn* InPawn)
{
    AMyAIController1* AIController = Cast<AMyAIController1>(GetController());
    //Set the seen target on the blackboard
    if (AIController)
    {
        GLog->Log("Oh hello there");
        AIController->SetSeenTarget(InPawn);
    }
}
```

And in mycontroller.cpp I added this to get my create variable in the blackboard:

```
{
    //Registers the Pawn that the AI has seen in the blackboard
    if (BlackboardComp)
    {
        BlackboardComp->SetValueAsObject(BlackboardKey, InPawn);
    }
}
```

here is my behavior tree to better understand: [image]

I would like the ia to stop following the player when it is no longer in its detection. Currently in the game when I arrive near the ia, the ia follows the player well but when I arrive has gone further the ia always follows me. So what I would like is for the ia to go back to its basic path when it sees more the player.

Thank you for your understanding and patience :)

Comment: What's the issue with the code? I would recommend you take some more time to detail the problem, if any. Thanks!

Comment: here I modified to make it more readable @AlanBirtles

Comment: it is done :) @AlanBirtles